# BCHRON Error in seq.default(my_hdr[[j]][1], my_hdr[[j]][2], by = 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Tags: r

I am calibrating 54 C14 dates and want to have all of them plotted in a curve but it isn't working ... I don't know what to do ...

```
ages1=BchronCalibrate(ages=c(5850,6640,6845,6885,7170,7270,7360,7365,
7560,7630,7780,6075,6865,7470,7870,7985,7990,8010,8020,8025,8090,8145,
8160,8200,8225,8230,8235,8250,8285,8305,8315,8370,8495,8560,8640,8660,
8710,8720,8730,8745,9450,5040,5450,7335,8195,8680,8705,8730,8710,8875,
8940,9350,3545,3550),ageSds=c(85,65,80,65,70,75,80,75,40,95,80,100,100,
95,80,95,70,75,80,95,80,65,65,65,65,65,75,70,90,65,80,70,70,85,70,90,
65,85,90,65,120,60,100,90,65,75,75,70,90,75,75,90,45,55),
calCurves=c("intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13", "intcal13", "intcal13", "intcal13",
 "intcal13", "intcal13", "intcal13", "intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13","intcal13",
"intcal13"))

summary(ages1)
```

When I type this:

```
plot(ages1)
```

I get the error message:

> Error in seq.default(my_hdr[[j]][1], my_hdr[[j]][2], by = 1) :
> wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Thanks for spotting this bug Shaddai Heidgen. Package has been updated and I've answered your query in full on the GitHub issues page where you put it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to contact the package maintainer:

```
library(Bchron)
maintainer("Bchron")
# [1] "Andrew Parnell <Andrew.Parnell@mu.ie>"
```

We can get your data to run if we take smaller chunks. The problem is that your
4th date is throwing the error and possibly others.

```
library(Bchron)

ages <- c(5850, 6640, 6845, 6885, 7170, 7270, 7360, 7365, 7560, 7630, 
7780, 6075, 6865, 7470, 7870, 7985, 7990, 8010, 8020, 8025, 8090, 
8145, 8160, 8200, 8225, 8230, 8235, 8250, 8285, 8305, 8315, 8370, 
8495, 8560, 8640, 8660, 8710, 8720, 8730, 8745, 9450, 5040, 5450, 
7335, 8195, 8680, 8705, 8730, 8710, 8875, 8940, 9350, 3545, 3550)

ageSds <- c(85, 65, 80, 65, 70, 75, 80, 75, 40, 95, 80, 100, 100, 95, 80, 
95, 70, 75, 80, 95, 80, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 75, 70, 90, 65, 80, 
70, 70, 85, 70, 90, 65, 85, 90, 65, 120, 60, 100, 90, 65, 75, 
75, 70, 90, 75, 75, 90, 45, 55)

calCurve <- rep("intcal13", 54)

OneDate <- BchronCalibrate(ages[1], ageSds[1], calCurve[1])
plot(OneDate)
```

One date works fine and so do the first 3, but the 4th date throws the error. Possibly because the highest density range is discontinuous/bimodal, but I'm not sure. Contact the maintainer at the email address above.

```
ThreeDates <- BchronCalibrate(ages[1:3], ageSds[1:3], calCurve[1:3])
plot(ThreeDates)

Date4 <- BchronCalibrate(ages[4], ageSds[4], calCurve[4])
summary(Date4)
# 95% Highest density regions for Date1
# $`94.3%`
# [1] 7594 7851
# 
# $`1.3%`
# [1] 7910 7851

plot(Date4)
# Error in seq.default(my_hdr[[j]][1], my_hdr[[j]][2], by = 1) : 
#   wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

[image: OneDate]

Comment: thanks so much!!!! i wrote him already since 2 days but he is not answering...

Comment: also a another thing, how can i plot calBP vs calBC? is it possible?

Comment: According to the manual page `?plot.BchronCalibratedDates`, it should be `ageScale=` "Either bp for years before present, bc for years BC/AD (BC will be negative), b2k for years before 2000. Others not supported (yet)."

Comment: Other possibilities are to try the [`rcarbon`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcarbon/index.html) package or use [OXCAL](https://c14.arch.ox.ac.uk/oxcal.html) and download the results to .csv files to get them into R. Also, [INTCAL20](https://c14.arch.ox.ac.uk/oxcalhelp/hlp_curves.html) is now available so you should probably use that.